# according to a value copy transpose of that section

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to make a script which can be do below picture function.

I have a list like yellow and i want to convert it like blue.

In this point function will check the list if see "!" it will keep that address1 then search again and it will be address2 now there will be a copy transpose function from address1:adress2 and write it.

And script should be continue on the next row with from address2 to adress3. I am looking something like this I hope i am clear.

[image]

Here's an example I'd like to parse:

```
! 
interface Ethernet0
nameif test
security-level 10
ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254
! 
interface Ethernet0
nameif test
security-level 10 
ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254 
! 
interface Ethernet2 
shutdown
no nameif 
security-level 0 
no ip address 
! 
interface Ethernet3 
no nameif 
security-level 0 
no ip address
```

Comment: So you want to convert a text file to some format displayable on a data grid ?

Comment: Tip: paste that text file as text instead of as an image

Comment: yes, you can see sections are separeted with !, so ever section i want to put in a row. i will use this as a database

Comment: !
interface Ethernet0
 nameif test
 security-level 10
 ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254
!
interface Ethernet0
 nameif test
 security-level 10
 ip address 10.10.88.50 255.255.255.254
!
interface Ethernet2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 security-level 0
 no ip address
!
interface Ethernet3
 no nameif
 security-level 0
 no ip address
!

Comment: When I meant paste it, I meant edit your question and while you're at it, use the formatting options in the editor, hold on I'll show you.

Comment: I thought you will use the same text to give script. because of that i paste it here

Comment: Are you under the impression that this is a "post your requirements and someone will code it for you"  type of site.  If so, you are mistaken.  You need to make an attempt at coding it and then ask for help on the part that is giving you problems.